# Understanding IP of service and Fargate pods exposed on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have a simple and personal EKS installation built with Terraform and I am trying to understand more at a lower level about how objects are distributed in the AWS+EKS scenario and its difference between a normal kubernetes installation. Unfortunately the EKS documentation is sometimes too large and I am not able to pinpoint the issue.

The EKS is private and attached to two private subnets and currently managed trough a bastion host with Kubectl. I have then successfully deployed a Fargate pod backed by a NodePorts service in a namespace via `kubectl` from the bastion.

I don't want to set up a perfect network, so I have no LoadBalancer in the radar for example. I am just trying to set up a service and invoke it with a simple `curl`.

**First doubt**

For start, by describing pod I get this address:

```
kubectl -n my-ns describe pod mypod-5dfdf74ddf-rfs8f

IP: 10.50.30.18
```

I recognized this IP as sourced from the CIDR Block of one the private subnet bound to EKS. Invoking it has of course no effect and results in error: `couldn't connect to...`

1. In my understanding, a pod should have an IP derived from a private pool, in this case it's an IP from a known CIDR block. It's because of Fargate ?
2. Providing that it's normal being blocked by trying to reach the pod directly via its IP. Who is blocking the `curl` in this case ? No security groups are attached to the pod

**Second doubt**

If I introspect the service:

```
kubectl -n my-ns describe svc myservice
```

I have the following result:

```
Name:                     myapp
Namespace:                my-ns
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=myapp
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       172.20.242.160
IPs:                      172.20.242.160
Port:                     <unset>  8888/TCP
TargetPort:               8888/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.50.30.18:8888
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I can recognize the `Port`, `TargetPort` and `NodePort` that I have declared in my .yml file and the endpoint IP which is the same as the Fargate pod. My attention goes however to the IP 172.20.242.160 which should be the exposed IP.

1. Where does this IP come from ? I have read in the doc that AWS creates a not visible VPC to isolate the cluster. Is there a way to `aws describe` such VPC ?
2. If it is the case how can I `curl` the cluster address from my bastion host without port forwarding ? Based on my knowledge VPC-A to VPC-B communication requires some network configuration it is not simply possible to invoke things directly.

Answer (score 0):

IP of Fargate pod is assigned from Fargate selected subnet.

Pod running in Fargate inherit by default security group of cluster, make sure that port 8888 is allowed from bastion to EKS cluster SG.

IP 172.20.242.160 came from cluster CIDR, in this case it”s likely 172.20.0.0/16. This IP is reachable from within cluster not from VPC.

To reach this IP/Pod make sure to exposed via loadbalancer for example. Othrwise, you can run pod within cluster and curl it’s port

Command for debug Pod: $ kubectl run tmp-shell --rm -i --tty --image nicolaka/netshoot